# Ajax Reading from a Database

Tags: php, sql, ajax, database

I'm developing a website/database solution which gives the administrator the option to sign into the webpage and perform actions on the database.

Currently they can add/delete/run pre-defined queries, however to 'edit' records in a table, I would like them to specify the primary key (ID) and then have ajax read in the values associated with that record and allow them to be changed.

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as stratton suggested you have  to use jquery/html on frontend and php/mysql on backend that will have the logic to handle the data you send and retrieve result that will be sent back to the user.
ex.
have a form that will send the id to search:

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="data" name="data"/>
<--send button-->
</form>
```

I suggest then to use jquery to send the form via ajax like this:

```
$(sendbutton).click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
s.ajax({
url: 'urlofyouphppage',
type: 'post',
data : {data: $("#data").val(), action: 'search_thing'}
success: function(data){
//the response from the php page to insert somewhere.
//beware that if you use json you will have to decode via parseJSON.
}
});
});
```

On you php side you will have to parse the post and then perform the action

```
<?php
 if($_POST['action'] == 'search_thing'){
$id = $_POST['data'];
//query for searching
//format the result data
echo $result; //or json_encode($result); if you want to use json
}
?>
```

This way you can create multiple logic step by setting each time a different action, and the anwer can be full html code that contains the "next step" to perform.

Answer (score 1):

make an ajax request (use jQuery) to a php script that reads from the database and outputs the return value in whatever format you prefer (html, json) then display it in the front end with javascript